# Why getting the state of one function works and from other not?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I was testing the states of different functions one for true and the other for false and one pass and the other fail. And I have no idea why it happens.

```js
//default
this.state = { passwordChangeOpen: false }

openPasswordChange () {
    this.setState({ passwordChangeOpen: true })
}

onClosePasswordChange () {
    this.setState({ passwordChangeOpen: false })
}
```

testing

```js
test('should', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<SettingsItemPassword {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    instance.openPasswordChange()
    expect(wrapper.state('passwordChangeOpen')).toBeTruthy()
})

test('should2', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<SettingsItemPassword {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    instance.onClosePasswordChange()
    expect(wrapper.state('passwordChangeOpen')).toBeFalsy()
})
```

The first test fails with an error

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props ...

But the second test pass.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your `SettingsItemPassword` component connecting to Redux? If so, you'll need to wrap it in a Redux `Provider`

Comment: @skovy and why one pass and the other not?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just keep in mind that setting the state is `async`. Since you are setting the default value as false, the second assertion will pass.

Just try to come up with something like this

```
test('should', done => {
    const wrapper = mount(<SettingsItemPassword {...mockPropsForComponent} />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    instance.openPasswordChange()
    setTimeout(() => {
      wrapper.update()
      expect(wrapper.state('passwordChangeOpen')).toBeTruthy()
      done()
    })
})
```